# Long form in React Native with TextInput with absolute position

Tags: react-native

I have a form in my React Native app that is a bit long. Plus I'm using `react-native-autocomplete-input` which requires absolute positioning on Android.

This makes things tricky. I'm constantly fighting to keep the keyboard not interfere with the form and keep form fields in correct order.

I started with `KeyboardAvoidingView` but when the user tries to go to the bottom of the form, things get all messed up because of absolute positioning required by the auto complete field.

I wanted to find out what suggestions those who've implemented long forms in React Native could offer.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with https://snack.expo.dev/. Currently, there's no standard solution for handling the Keyboardboard overlapping other UI components. There's a fix in the upcoming React  Native Release. 

Meanwhile,  It currently resolved by hacks.

Comment: Do you mean the fix will be in 0.67? If so, that's good news. You're right about trying to make things work through hack. The one that works the best as far as behavior goes is `KeyboardAwareScrollView` but I have `autocomplete` in my form which seems to produce a list and I keep running into "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain scrollviews".

Comment: It will be available in next release 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/49a1460a379e3a71358fb38888477ce6ea17e81a